# Is it correct to say 'a four doored car'?

Tags: adjectives, compound-adjectives

If I describe a motor car as a 'four door car' I am making 'door' an adjective. It forms a compound adjective with the word 'four' and it adjectivally describes an attribute of the car, and is therefore singular as we do not inflect or pluralise adjectives in English.

Some people would hyphenate the compound adjective 'four-door'.

But I have overheard the expression 'four doored car' where the noun 'door' is (I assume) being made into a verb as we would make 'floor' into a verb ('the room was floored with linoleum' becomes 'a linoleum floored room').

Is this correct English ?

(I am referring to British English for context.)

Comment: In the US "four-door", as a car descriptor, would almost always have the hyphen, whether it was a-doored or not.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/door#Verb) lists the verbal polyseme; it often shows changes in acceptability before more traditional dictionaries.

Comment: Well, *door* absolutely is a verb in some contexts, @OldBrixtonian. It's something careless drivers do to cyclists.

Comment: For me, four doored means converted from a car that has two or one door. Whereas a four door car was built that way- specifically designed for four doors.

Comment: Google supports the view that the hyphen is optional in the UK. Indeed a single website from a major UK car dealer has both hyphenated and unhyphenated examples.

Comment: Not worthy of a full answer, but just to note that it’s the norm to include the BOOT as a “door” with a hatchback. So it would actually be a FIVE-doored car…

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: Yes. Good point. Thanks.

Comment: @TRiG: Thanks. I've narrowly escaped such doorings myself but didn't know they had a verb.

Comment: Thanks, @jsw28: TBH I was thinking I was in ELL when I posted it. It might have been useful to a learner there, but it lacked the diligence expected in EL&U!

Comment: @ChrisMelville An additional note is that the rule of thumb on whether the boot is a door is whether the rear windshield is attached to the boot or the body. On a hatchback, the windshield is attached to the boot, so it's a door (or a hatch, hence the name), and why they're 3-/5-door. On a sedan, it's typically not attached, so it'll be a 4-door.

Comment: I expect -doored does exist as dialectal (or idiolectal) usage [kind of like my brother-in-law's "soured cream" (which in my world is cream that has gone bad, while "sour cream" is purposely cultured and delicious)] and the intended meaning is pretty transparent, but I wouldn't suggest using it regularly.

Comment: @ChrisMelville Actually the fifth door is not the boot in the case of a hatchback, it's the tailgate. The space below the parcel shelf can be thought of as a boot (trunk in the US) but the door is definitely a tailgate and not a boot lid.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> If I describe a motor car as a 'four door car' I am making 'door' an adjective.

No. Although it has an adjectival function.

You are using "door" as an attributive noun that, itself, is modified by "four".

four-door = noun phrase acting attributively.

The hyphen is not necessary, but if you use it, use it consistently:

> *In four-door vehicles, the B-posts are located between the front and rear
> doors of a vehicle.* [Vehicle Rescue and Extrication: Principles and Practice](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=d5txDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA251&dq=%22a%20four%20door%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSiM3kvM3zAhUKQ0EAHVDlBEsQ6AF6BAhBEAI#v=onepage&q=%22four%22&f=false) By David Sweet

> *It would be true of both two and four door coachbuilt cars as well; i.e., the C pillar could be a half-pillar type stopping at the belt- or waistline (q.v.)*, ([Illustrated Dictionary of Automobile Body Styles](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6GQoDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA119&dq=%22a%20four%20door%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSiM3kvM3zAhUKQ0EAHVDlBEsQ6AF6BAhMEAI#v=onepage&q=%22four%20door%22&f=false), 2d ed. By Lennart W. Haajanen)

> Is it correct to say 'a four doored car'?

Yes, "four-doored" is an adjective but it is rare and rather formal and I have not heard it other than as a predicative adjective - "The car is four-doored." You would usually say "The car is a four-door."

Comment: UK note - in 1961 my father bought a _two-door_ Ford Anglia, out first car, and in 1966 a _four-door_ Ford Cortina.

Comment: “Four door sedan” has been a stock phrase from police dramas, and maybe real life, for as long as I can remember.  “The suspect drove off in a four door sedan.”

Comment: @MichaelHarvey is the OP asking about *60-year-old* British English usage? The question doesn't say so.

Comment: @alephzero I was hoping to show that the hyphenated way of talking about the number of doors possessed by a car is both long established (it has a provenance) and widespread.  I am very sorry if I have offended you. _Have a nice day_

Answer (score 18):

For whatever it’s worth, the OED has *four-door* for the adjective. They provide this citation:

> - **1957**   P. Frank *Seven Days to Never* i. 13
>      A four-door sedan.

So probably that’s what you should **say** unless you mean something
else than is meant by the way their citation uses it.  See below for
such contrasting examples using other pairs than yours.

What you **write** is of course up to you. These normally are hyphenated
in writing when used attributively, but not always: there are still a
lot of *five pound notes* in circulation.

---

Usually you have only one of either "a № NOUN something" versus
"a № NOUNed something" in common use, but which it is depends on other factors.

For one thing, measure phrases used attributively seldom inflect their
nouns for number the way they often do when used predicatively.  So you
have things like:

- a twenty-one-gun salute
- a five-acre farm
- a five-day week
- the four-colour problem
- a four-letter word
- running a four-minute mile
- a four-stroke engine
- the million-dollar question

Compare those with “more adjectival” NOUNed versions:

- a three-legged stool
- a five-fingered jack
- a game of four-handed cribbage
- some five-leaved grass
- a two-sepalled blossom
- that hundred-headed thistle

Nobody today says ❌ *a five-dayed week* because normally such measure
phrases used attributively start out with an uninflected noun, so you only
have *a four-day week*.  But we **used** to say ❌ *a four-inched whatever*,
even though we now say only *a four-inch whatever*.

Sometimes both versions exist. If so, they **might** mean the same
thing the way they do in *one-finger salute* and *one-fingered salute*.

But they **might also** mean different things as they do in *a three-foot dog* versus
*a three-footed dog*, or *a five-point essay* versus *a five-pointed
star*.

It really just depends — there are incalculably many more such example
pairs out there, both contrasting ones and non-contrasting ones.

Comment: Another variation would be cases where the numerical phrase comes *after* the noun it modifies.  The only example I can think of are musical compositions for *"piano four-hands"*.

Answer (score 10):

Both *four-door car* and *four-doored car* are correctly constructed according to English grammar rules. Which one is more idiomatic based on actual usage is a separate issue.

The use of a phrase *four-doored* car does not necessarily imply the existence of a verb *to door.* English *-ed* has multiple functions. It can form the simple past tense of a verb, as in *They proved it.* It can form the past participle of a verb, as in *I have watched it before.* Some adjectives, such as *excited,* are derived from a verbal past participle ending in *-ed.* But a third function of *-ed* is forming adjectives directly from nouns (or nominal phrases) with the meaning "possessing [noun]".

Some examples: *small-minded, two-faced, cross-eyed, brown-haired.*

These are all idiomatic and usual, even though it is not usual to say *"They are minded small", *"They are faced two", "They are eyed cross", *"They are haired brown". Also, there is no implication that the state is a result of some change, as there often would be with a participial adjective (describing someone as *brown-haired* does not imply that their hair became brown after previously being a different color).

The Oxford English Dictionary has a separate entry for this use of *-ed,* which says the precise details of the etymology are unclear. Some quotations:

- > In modern English, and even in Middle English, the form affords no means of distinguishing between the genuine examples of this suffix and those participial adjectives in *-ed* [...] which are ultimately [from] nouns through unrecorded verbs
- > The suffix is now **added without restriction to any noun** from which it is desired to form an adjective with the sense ‘possessing, provided with, characterized by’ (something); e.g. in *toothed, booted, wooded, moneyed, cultured, diseased, jaundiced,* etc., and in parasynthetic derivatives, as *dark-eyed, seven-hilled, leather-aproned,* etc.
- > **Groundless** objections have been made to the use of such words by writers unfamiliar with the history of the language

[bolding added]